# CSS in Rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Rails 3.0. How I can include a CSS that I put in `/public/stylesheets` into a View file in `/app/views/posts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) was introduced in Rails 3.1.

In the previous versions (including Rails 3.0.0), you can link to CSS files with `stylesheet_link_tag`.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "main" %>
```

Including the above code in the view file includes `public/stylesheets/main.css` file.

More details at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.0/layouts_and_rendering.html#linking-to-css-files-with-stylesheet_link_tag

Answer (score 0):

You should put it in `/public/assets/` (it's the convention) and then you can do this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "example" %>
```

Or you can put it inside `public/assets/stylesheets/` and do:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "stylesheets/example" %>
```

Comment: Is `/public/assets` only available for versions of Rails newer than 3.0? Because in my `public` folder I can see the folders `/public/images`, `/public/javascripts`, and `/public/stylesheets`.